# SignatureDoesNotMatch on PutObject - Working on GetObject

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a signed url for putObject in S3. My method for doing this for GetObject works fine, so my credentials are working.

I have turned off all blocks of public access so it should be publicly available.

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPutObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::adobe-sign-test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

I have tried using both the s3 library and now in this example the s3manager. But when I try to put an object using the Signed URL I am receiving an XML error telling me the SignatureDoesNotMatch.

Here is the code for both the working GET, and the failing PUT.

```
func getPresignedURL(bucket, key, operation string, expiresIn int64, region string, s3AccessKeyID string, s3SecretAccessKey string) string {
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(region),
        Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(
            s3AccessKeyID,
            s3SecretAccessKey,
            "",
        ),
    }))

    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    if operation == "PutObject" {
        // Generate a pre-signed URL for a PutObject operation
        uploadUrl, _ := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(key),
            ACL:    aws.String("bucket-owner-full-control"),
        })

        return uploadUrl.Location
    }

    // Generate a pre-signed URL for a GetObject operation
    req, _ := uploader.S3.GetObjectRequest(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })

    getUrl, err := req.Presign(time.Duration(expiresIn) * time.Second)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return ""
    }

    return getUrl
}
```

Here is how I try to PUT a file using curl:
`curl -X PUT -T some-file.jpg "https://adobe-sign-test.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/hejsan.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQJGLAAKTL3QQFZ73%2F20230706%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230706T074846Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=5eb429ee8efc1c8ffcae64d77a588119cfde81512bc5c4516a1120b20e26cac7"`

This is the error message for the put operation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAQJGLAAKTL3QQFZ73</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230706T074846Z
20230706/eu-north-1/s3/aws4_request
7666f6675cc3fe3a3aa20f98928aeccd4b9bc851666fcf03fb425d5819d7e72d</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>5eb429ee8efc1c8ffcae64d77a588119cfde81512bc5c4516a1120b20e26cac7</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 32 33 30 37 30 36 54 30 37 34 38 34 36 5a 0a 32 30 32 33 30 37 30 36 2f 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 37 36 36 36 66 36 36 37 35 63 63 33 66 65 33 61 33 61 61 32 30 66 39 38 39 32 38 61 65 63 63 64 34 62 39 62 63 38 35 31 36 36 36 66 63 66 30 33 66 62 34 32 35 64 35 38 31 39 64 37 65 37 32 64</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>PUT
/hejsan.jpg
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAQJGLAAKTL3QQFZ73%2F20230706%2Feu-north-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20230706T074846Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=3600&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
host:adobe-sign-test.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com

host
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest><CanonicalRequestBytes>50 55 54 0a 2f 68 65 6a 73 61 6e 2e 6a 70 67 0a 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 41 6c 67 6f 72 69 74 68 6d 3d 41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 43 72 65 64 65 6e 74 69 61 6c 3d 41 4b 49 41 51 4a 47 4c 41 41 4b 54 4c 33 51 51 46 5a 37 33 25 32 46 32 30 32 33 30 37 30 36 25 32 46 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 25 32 46 73 33 25 32 46 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 44 61 74 65 3d 32 30 32 33 30 37 30 36 54 30 37 34 38 34 36 5a 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3d 33 36 30 30 26 58 2d 41 6d 7a 2d 53 69 67 6e 65 64 48 65 61 64 65 72 73 3d 68 6f 73 74 0a 68 6f 73 74 3a 61 64 6f 62 65 2d 73 69 67 6e 2d 74 65 73 74 2e 73 33 2e 65 75 2d 6e 6f 72 74 68 2d 31 2e 61 6d 61 7a 6f 6e 61 77 73 2e 63 6f 6d 0a 0a 68 6f 73 74 0a 55 4e 53 49 47 4e 45 44 2d 50 41 59 4c 4f 41 44</CanonicalRequestBytes><RequestId>SMFDTR996NQE9DDV</RequestId><HostId>VehdLPGdnoVZclkNKs2+lTjFpAssA1Xe+HZSj5ZCCVK2QnumQHqzsePFg3TWWaai3+vqGgnwxpjMd3b8526I7Q==</HostId></Error>
```

Comment: I haven't used the Go SDK, but this seems like completely the wrong approach: you're digging into the internals of the uploader, which will sign differently depending on whether it uses a multi-part of single-part upload. A five-second search of the S3 documentation page turned up `PresignClient`, which seems much more likely to do what you want: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/s3#PresignClient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [example in the AWS SDK Code Library for Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_PresignedUrl_section.html) that has GET and PUT with presigned URLs for S3, maybe that will help. You can clone the repository and run these examples yourself following the instructions in the README. This sample has the methods and then there is a console application that demonstrates running them.

```
// GetObject makes a presigned request that can be used to get an object from a bucket.
// The presigned request is valid for the specified number of seconds.
func (presigner Presigner) GetObject(
    bucketName string, objectKey string, lifetimeSecs int64) (*v4.PresignedHTTPRequest, error) {
    request, err := presigner.PresignClient.PresignGetObject(context.TODO(), &s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    }, func(opts *s3.PresignOptions) {
        opts.Expires = time.Duration(lifetimeSecs * int64(time.Second))
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get a presigned request to get %v:%v. Here's why: %v\n",
            bucketName, objectKey, err)
    }
    return request, err
}



// PutObject makes a presigned request that can be used to put an object in a bucket.
// The presigned request is valid for the specified number of seconds.
func (presigner Presigner) PutObject(
    bucketName string, objectKey string, lifetimeSecs int64) (*v4.PresignedHTTPRequest, error) {
    request, err := presigner.PresignClient.PresignPutObject(context.TODO(), &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    }, func(opts *s3.PresignOptions) {
        opts.Expires = time.Duration(lifetimeSecs * int64(time.Second))
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get a presigned request to put %v:%v. Here's why: %v\n",
            bucketName, objectKey, err)
    }
    return request, err
}



// DeleteObject makes a presigned request that can be used to delete an object from a bucket.
func (presigner Presigner) DeleteObject(bucketName string, objectKey string) (*v4.PresignedHTTPRequest, error) {
    request, err := presigner.PresignClient.PresignDeleteObject(context.TODO(), &s3.DeleteObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        Key:    aws.String(objectKey),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get a presigned request to delete object %v. Here's why: %v\n", objectKey, err)
    }
    return request, err
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't aware of the aws-sdk-go-v2 package for Go, these worked on first try while the v1 did not.